# Puppeteer Jasmine Travis-CI with multiple spec files just run the first spec

Tags: jasmine, travis-ci, puppeteer

I having some troubles to make **puppeteer** with **jasmine** works in **travis-ci** like in my local repo. I'm writing a kind of component compiler similar to **Svelte** but with multiple differences. The point is that, in my pc i run all the test successfully but when i do a pull request and travis start to work, only the first spec test file works properlly. Here are the files that do the test job:

**Update**:

Here's the code:

**.travis.yml**

```
dist: trusty
sudo: required
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "node"
  - "9"
install:
  - npm i
script:
  - npm run build
  - npm run build:test:components
  - npm test
cache:
  directories:
    - "node_modules"
```

**test/index.ts**

```js
import Jasmine from 'jasmine';
import JasmineConsoleReporter from 'jasmine-console-reporter';

// setup Jasmine
const jasmine = new Jasmine({});
jasmine.loadConfig({
  spec_dir: 'test/specs',
  spec_files: ['**/*[sS]pec.js'],
  random: false,
  seed: null,
  stopSpecOnExpectationFailure: false
});
jasmine.jasmine['DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL'] = 15000;

// setup console reporter
const reporter = new JasmineConsoleReporter({
  colors: 1,
  emoji: true,
  verbosity: 4,
  cleanStack: 1,
  timeUnit: 'ms',
  listStyle: 'indent',
  activity: 'bouncingBar',
  timeThreshold: { ok: 500, warn: 1000, ouch: 3000 },
});

// initialize and execute
jasmine.env.clearReporters();
jasmine.addReporter(reporter);
jasmine.execute();
```

**test/utils.ts**

```js
import { resolve } from 'path';
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
import puppeteer, { LaunchOptions, Browser, Page, JSHandle, ScriptTagOptions } from 'puppeteer';

const width = 1366;
const height = 768;

export async function getBrowser(options: LaunchOptions = {}) {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch(Object.assign({
    headless: true,
    args: [`--window-size=${width},${height}`, '--no-sandbox']
  }, options));
  return browser;
}

export async function getPage(browser: Browser, ...files: string[]) {
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setContent('');
  await page.setViewport({ width, height });
  const scripts: ScriptTagOptions[] = files
    .map(file => ({ content: readFileSync(resolve(__dirname, `./components/${file}.js`), 'utf8') }));
  scripts.unshift({ content: scriptInit(files[0][0].toUpperCase() + files[0].slice(1)) });
  scripts.reverse().forEach(async script => {
    await page.addScriptTag(script);
  });
  return page;
}

export async function getComponent<T, K>(page: Page, component: string): Promise<[JSHandle<T>, JSHandle<K>]> {
  const windowHandle = await page.evaluateHandle(() => window);
  const instance: JSHandle<K> = await windowHandle.getProperty('instance');
  const Component: JSHandle<T> = await windowHandle.getProperty(component);
  windowHandle.dispose();
  return [Component, instance];
}

export async function exec<T extends any>(handle: JSHandle<T>, cb: (obj: T) => any) {
  return handle.evaluate(cb);
}

function scriptInit(component: string) {
  const i = 'instance';
  return `const main = document.createElement('main');
  document.body.append(main);
  const ${i} = new ${component}();
  ${i}.$mount('main');
  window.${i} = ${i};`;
}
```

This is an example spec that currentlly doesn't work because only the first spec file pass the test. All spec files are [here](https://github.com/InDIOS/trebor/blob/development/test/specs)

```js
import { Page, Browser, JSHandle, ElementHandle } from 'puppeteer';
import { getBrowser, getPage, getComponent, exec } from '../utils';

describe('Component Conditions', () => {
  let page: Page;
  let browser: Browser;
  let instance: JSHandle<Component>;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    browser = await getBrowser();
    page = await getPage(browser, 'condition');
    [, instance] = await getComponent<typeof Component, Component>(page, 'Condition');
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await browser.close();
  });

  it('`$if` should be rendered', async () => {
    const span: ElementHandle<HTMLSpanElement> = await page.$('main span');
    expect(await exec(span, s => s.textContent)).toBe('1');
  });

  it('`$else-if` should be rendered', async () => {
    await exec(instance, i => i.$set('condition', 2));
    const span: ElementHandle<HTMLSpanElement> = await page.$('main span');
    expect(await exec(span, s => s.textContent)).toBe('2');
  });

  it('`$else` should be rendered', async () => {
    await exec(instance, i => i.$set('condition', 3));
    const span: ElementHandle<HTMLSpanElement> = await page.$('main span');
    expect(await exec(span, s => s.textContent)).toBe('other');
  });

  it('`$if` only should be rendered', async () => {
    const div: ElementHandle<HTMLDivElement> = await page.$('main div');
    expect(await exec(div, d => d.textContent)).toBe('1');
  });

  it('`$if` only should be hidden', async () => {
    await exec(instance, i => i.$set('condition_1', 2));
    let div: ElementHandle<null> = await page.$('main div');
    expect(div).toBeNull();
  });
});
```

to run the test:

```sh
node test/index.js
```

The repo is [TreborJS](https://github.com/InDIOS/trebor) and i'm working on the development brach

This is the output of travis: https://travis-ci.org/InDIOS/trebor/jobs/618791065?utm_medium=notification&utm_source=github_status

I hope you guys can help me soon and very thanks in advances

PS: Forgive my english, i'm not an english speaker

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, add your code in your post rather than external links. They can disappear and then, there is no question.

Comment: Thanks for advice me, i have updated the question and putted the code